# SUM IIF expression result

Tags: sql, sql-server

in this select i need the sum result the IIF expression, but when i execute this query obtain only first IIF statement. Any suggestion?? Thanks

```
SELECT conto, desconto, date, codoperaio, SUM(IIF(totcasse ='1',SUM(totcasse),0)+
                                              IIF(totcasse ='6',SUM(totcasse*3),0)+
                                              IIF(totcasse ='8',SUM(totcasse*4),0)+
                                              IIF(totcasse ='10',SUM(totcasse*5),0)) as Kilogrammi
FROM dbo.Import
where totcasse BETWEEN 1 and 10
Group by conto, desconto, date,codoperaio, totcasse
```

Comment: Remove totcasse from GROUP BY clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If am not wrong you are looking for this

```
SELECT conto,
       desconto,
       date,
       codoperaio,
       Sum(CASE totcasse WHEN '1' THEN totcasse ELSE 0 END) + 
       Sum(CASE totcasse WHEN '6' THEN totcasse * 3 ELSE 0 END) + 
       Sum(CASE totcasse WHEN '8' THEN totcasse * 4 ELSE 0 END) + 
       Sum(CASE totcasse WHEN '10' THEN totcasse * 5 ELSE 0 END)
FROM   dbo.Import
WHERE  totcasse in (1,6,8,10)
GROUP  BY conto,
          desconto,
          date,
          codoperaio
```

or

```
SELECT conto,
       desconto,
       date,
       codoperaio,
       Sum(CASE totcasse
             WHEN '1' THEN totcasse 
             WHEN '6' THEN totcasse * 3
             WHEN '8' THEN totcasse * 4
             WHEN '10' THEN totcasse * 5
           END)
FROM   dbo.Import
WHERE  totcasse in (1,6,8,10)
GROUP  BY conto,
          desconto,
          date,
          codoperaio
```

Comment: Strange use of the Case function. I would change it to
sum(Case totcasse
When 1 then totcasse
when 6 then totcasse * 3
when 8 then totcasse * 4
when 10 then totcasse * 5
else 0
end )

Comment: @PSVSupporter initially that was my answer but this looked more readable

Comment: Thanks your solution is perfect.

Comment: Does the second query even run? I could see mis-matched parenthesis. And I didn't understand that '+' sign after first case. Is this as per your  requirement?

Comment: @AkankshaSingh - Dude, Refresh the page

Comment: After your edit, It still does not address the default case i.e. consider value as  '0'. You might want to edit it again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT conto, desconto, date, codoperaio, IIF(totcasse ='1',SUM(totcasse),0)+
                                              IIF(totcasse ='6',SUM(totcasse*3),0)+
                                              IIF(totcasse ='8',SUM(totcasse*4),0)+
                                              IIF(totcasse ='10',SUM(totcasse*5),0) as Kilogrammi
FROM dbo.Import
where totcasse BETWEEN 1 and 10
Group by conto, desconto, date,codoperaio, totcasse
```

Comment: It looks like the same query.. ?

Comment: @PSVSupporter He removed the `SUM` in the `Kilogrammi` but not explained that in the answer

Comment: yup , i only remove SUM, + sign doing sum of all. So no need of Sum fuction

Answer (score 0):

Don't group by totcasse.
And, don't use SUM after IIF. I have an older SQL Server version, so I cannot test IIF, but I think it should be like this:

```
SELECT conto,
       desconto,
       date,
       codoperaio,
       Sum(iif( totcasse = 1, totcasse, 
           iif( totcasse = 6, totcasse * 3, 
           iif( totcasse = 8, totcasse * 4, 
           iif( totcasse = 10, totcasse * 5, 0))))) as Kilogrammi
FROM   dbo.Import
WHERE  totcasse >= 1 
  AND  totcasse <= 10
GROUP  BY conto,
          desconto,
          date,
          codoperaio
```

Make sure there are not possible values of, for example, 3 or 9 totcasse. Or else they won't be calculated. Or else, replace 0 with totcasse.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `CASE` statement,

```
SELECT conto, desconto, date, codoperaio,
        SUM(CASE totcasse
            WHEN '1' THEN totcasse
            WHEN '6' THEN totcasse*3
            WHEN '8' THEN totcasse*4
            WHEN '10' THEN totcasse*5
            ELSE 0 END
        )as Kilogrammi
FROM dbo.Import
where totcasse BETWEEN 1 and 10
Group by conto, desconto, date,codoperaio, totcasse
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three obvious problems in the query.

1. You cannot nest the `SUM()` function.
2. You have `totcasse` in the `group by` but you seem to want to combine these in a single row.
3. Your `WHERE` clause treats `totcasse` as a number rather than a string.

In addition, `case` is the better way to write the query rather than `iif()`.  (`case` is ANSI standard SQL; `iif()` is in SQL Server for backwards compatibility to MS Access and who wants to be backwards?)

I am guessing that this is the query query you want:

```
SELECT conto, desconto, date, codoperaio,
       SUM(CASE WHEN totcasse ='1' THEN totcasse
                WHEN totcasse ='6' THEN totcasse * 3
                WHEN totcasse ='8' THEN totcasse * 4
                WHEN totcasse ='10' THEN totcasse * 5
                ELSE 0
           END) as Kilogrammi
FROM dbo.Import
where totcasse IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10')
Group by conto, desconto, date, codoperaio;
```

Note the `WHERE` clause.  When you are using *strings*, then the expression:

```
where totcasse between '1' and '10'
```

is basically only going to return values that start with `'10'`.  Do not mix types in comparisons.

Comment: IIF is introduced in SQL Server 2012 as a simplified syntax for CASE. SQL Server internally converts the IIF syntax to CASE. But this has no effect in performance.
So CASE is not 'better', but rather a preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT conto
, desconto
, date
, codoperaio
, SUM(CASE totcasse 
      WHEN 1 THEN totcasse
      WHEN 6 THEN totcasse*3
      WHEN 8 THEN totcasse*4
      WHEN 10 THEN totcasse*5
      ELSE 0
      END) AS Kilogrammi
FROM dbo.Import
where totcasse BETWEEN 1 and 10
Group by conto, desconto, date,codoperaio
```